# How to code C in a x64 bit machine?

Tags: compiler-construction, cygwin, 64-bit, mingw, turbo-c

My new PC is Dell Inspiron 580s which is a x64 machine. Before which I used to code in TURBO C++ in my x86 machine.

Since I was unable to run TURBO C++ in the new system. I installed NetBeans 6 IDE for which we need to install the compiler (CYGWIN) manually and so I did. But I'm unable to code in NetBeans.

After lots of search I heard of C-Free. which uses MinGW Compiler. I installed it but it too doesn't work.

**Please help me setup a 'C' coding environment.**

Comment: Do you have more details? What did you do that didn't work? What error messages did you see? What happened when you tried to compile the classic `Hello, World!` example? Did you get that far?

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently on a x64 machine (Windows 7). Netbeans with MingW-gcc/g++ works fine for me. Also, Visual Studio 2010 works with no problems.

This might help you: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic8393.html

And: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows